# What is wrong with this code, it's not deleting the data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i am importing csv file to delete the  mysql database according articleno  but its not deleting

```
if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            $fss = '.addslashes($data[1]).';
            mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno =  $fss ");
        }
}
```

Comment: Does your `do {` have a `while`?

Comment: You forgot the quotes for the array keys on `$_FILES`.  `$_FILES['csv']['tmp_name']`

Comment: Also, FYI `addslashes` is ***not*** a good way to prevent against SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
  $fss = '.addslashes($data[1]).';
```

to

```
  $fss = addslashes($data[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$fss = '.addslashes($data[1]).';
```

Change it to

```
$fss = addslashes($data[1]);
```

because now your query looks like

```
DELETE from  contacts where articleno = .addslashes($data[1]).
```

:)

Comment: } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));

Answer (score 0):

Because $fss is inserted in a string it doesn't have to be a string. Removing the quotes around the variable should suffice

Try checking what $fss is after setting it to 'addslashes($data[1])'. Is it the value you thought it would be?

Comment: i removed qoutes but still not deleting

Comment: Did you try printing out what your query looks like instead of running it directly?

Comment: <?php  

//connect to the database 
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","0000",""); 
mysql_select_db("uuuu",$connect); //select the table 


if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

    //get the csv file 
    $file = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
 
            
   
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
  
 $fss = addslashes($data[1]);
  mysql_query("DELETE from  contacts where articleno =  $fss ");
                
  
  
        } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'")); 
    

} 

?>

Comment: i am using  $fss = addslashes($data[1]); but still no result

Comment: I know what you are using but what is the result value, and is it what you expected it to be?